# Best way to separate HTML of the Razor code

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, separation-of-concerns

We have some .NET back-end developers and some front-end (HTML & CSS) developers who have the minimum knowledge about ASP.NET MVC and Razor. This makes it hard to let both back-end and front-end developers work on the views directly. Therefore, normally back-end developers create a complex html page (using some frameworks) which then needed to be transferred into razor views. We normally end up doing this by copy and pasting the markup which makes the whole process so slow.

Often after our back-end developers add code to the pages (e.g. foreach loops), front-end developers have to make some changes to fix bugs or change the UI (for some reasons) and then they find it impossible to work on a page which carries .NET code too.

My question is that what is the best way of isolating these two concerns, which are building the html code and adding the razor/c# code.

I was thinking of having a pure HTML view and build the Razor view around it but I am not sure how this can be implemented technically.

Comment: Razor syntax isn't exactly hard to read or use. Tell your front end devs to read up on the 5 keywords they need to know to use Razor?

Comment: It's not as easy as learning some keywords! They must know a lot more than that such as the whole HTML extension methods (@HTML), @Url objects etc. There should be a better way of separating these concerns.

Comment: That is all less than a day's work and the documentation is easily available online. You will do your project less harm if you just introduce them to Razor.

Comment: Just make them write down some mock markup, 1 or 2 elements. Then the code can overwrite the static "dummy" values.

Answer (score 4):

You need to separate your concerns further. Seems like your razor view do too much, if there is C# code embedded. All the logic must be done inside of controllers of classes that provide data to controllers. No further processing should happen in views. **Ever**

The most complex construct in views should be `@foreach` or `@for` loops to create tables/lists. Also create url via `@Url` and `ActionLink` because that's where these belongs. Anything more complex than this must not be allowed.

And this will make your front-end guys life easier, along with advise to read-up about razor syntax.